# SwiftUI: deleting Managed Object from cell view crashes app [non-optional property]?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I posted this question:

[SwiftUI: deleting Managed Object from cell view crashes app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73159270/swiftui-deleting-managed-object-from-cell-view-crashes-app)

as I worked on trying to understand why it crashes, I tried to change the model `Item` to have `timestamp` NON-optional:

```
extension Item {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Item> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
    }

    @NSManaged public var timestamp: Date

}

extension Item : Identifiable {

}
```

As Asperi pointed out, using this:

```
  if let timestamp = item.timestamp {
    Text(timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)
  }
```

does fix the crash when `timestamp` is optional.

However, this is just some code I am testing to understand how to properly build my views. I need to use models that do not have optional properties, and because of that I can't resort to use the provided answer to the question I linked to above.

So this question is to address the scenario where my `CellView` uses a property that is **not optional** on a ManagedObject.

If I were to put this code straight in the `ContentView` without using the `CellView` it does not crash. This does not crash:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    } label: {
//                        CellView(item: item)
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter) // <<- CRASH ON DELETE
                            Button {
                                withAnimation {
                                    viewContext.delete(item)
                                    try? viewContext.save()
                                }
                                
                            } label: {
                                Text("DELETE")
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach { item in
                viewContext.delete(item)
            }

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I need to know how to keep the `CellView`, use `@ObservedObject` and make this work. In this case is not a big deal to do that, but in real cases where the `CellView` is much bigger this approach does not scale well. Regardless, why would using `@ObservedObject` in a separate view be wrong anyway?

So, why is the app crashing when the `timestamp` is NOT optional in the model?
Why is the view trying to redraw the CellView for an Item that was deleted? How can this be fixed?

FOR CLARITY I AM POSTING HERE THE NEW CODE FOR THE NON-OPTIONAL CASE, SO YOU DON'T HAVE TO GO BACK AND LOOK AT THE LINKED QUESTION AND THEN CHANGE IT TO NON-OPTIONAL. THIS IS THE CODE THAT CRASHES IN ITS ENTIRETY:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    } label: {
                        CellView(item: item)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach { item in
                viewContext.delete(item)
            }

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CellView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var item:Item
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Text(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter) // <<- CRASH ON DELETE
            
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    viewContext.delete(item)
                    try? viewContext.save()
                }
                
            } label: {
                Text("DELETE")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
        }
        
    }
    
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe this happens because after you delete a core data object it can still exist in memory but all its properties are set to nil. The object is more of a placeholder than a real object after the delete.

Comment: CoreData autogenerates properties always as optional, even if you disable optional in model itself, specifically because of lazy fetch, data drops, etc. I've got this only with manual class link. I don't think it is good practice with CoreData, so return better to optional interface and handle it explicitly as in previous post.

Comment: All great input. If MOs aren't supposed to be used in views then why of we have things like @FetchRequest etc... Anyway, I agree almost everything provided above. Seems something is missing in CoreData/SwiftUI integration though.

Comment: Thanks for a great thread and discussion. I have an almost identical problem in a navigation stack. If I create an object in a top view, and delete it right away — no issue. However, if I the navigate to a detail view for this new object, return to the top view, and then delete it — that’s when the crash happens. Like you, I’m using non-optionals. Asperi’s solution worked for me. And like Nico wrote in another answer, it was a date that caused the crash for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explicit handling is needed in anyway, because of specifics of CoreData engine. After object delete it can still be in memory (due to kept references), but it becomes in Fault state, that's why code autogeneration always set NSManagedObject properties to optional (even if they are not optional in model).

Here is a fix for this specific case. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
if !item.isFault {
    Text(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter) // << NO CRASH
}
```

Comment: Checking for fault makes sense as far as preventing the crash in this one line. And it's probably going to be the answer to the question. I am battled because I feel like there's something missing here. All input provided is great. I also tired to put the fault check right into the ForEach, and that still crashes. The question `Why would using @ObservedObject in a separate view be wrong anyway?` still has no clear answer. It seems to me like CoreData/SwiftUI here has some serious holes still. ‍♂️

Comment: it keeps reference to fault object... but we do not control when/how views are recreated or refreshed, so it becomes view is refreshed with invalid object. I recommend on usage default generated optional properties, because they represent the nature of objects and indicate that such properties MUST be handled explicitly.

Comment: I get what you're saying and it simply seems 100% right to me. So, no argument there. I'm trying to see how to scale this solution. Checking for every property in a large object is a nightmare. Nothing wrong with your answer. I'm just processing all of this. Thinking.

Comment: I resorted to create the cell view inside of the ContentView `func cellView(item:Item) -> some View { ...` and there is no crash anymore. @ObservedObject simply keeps the reference around too long for some reason. I think Apple truly missed some good implementation here. ‍♂️

Comment: Just as an update. It looks like ManagedObjects work great in SwiftUI views as long as they are used directly in views where the `@FetchRequest` is directly installed on. Passing a ManagedObject to subviews that take them in as @ObservedObjects is not a good pattern.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

The problem for me was that I tried to make as much as possible non optional in CoreData. This works for many cases but with `Date` it might lead to crashes. I declared my date property as optional again and everything worked without crashing.